# Create new rows to column bind

Tags: r

I want to combine columns of a list into a single dataframe, however, some lists are of different lengths. The maximum length is 17, and I've thought of a way around this and that's by creating a new row to match the maximum length number for column concatenation.

If row `layers` do not match in length, then fill the missing value between 1 and 17, and replace the values column `enc_` with the number 0.

Here's a sample of the dataset:

```
[[1]]
   layer pland_01_evergreen_needleleaf
1      1                   0.016832782
2      2                   0.024552628
3      3                   0.024377985
4      4                   0.009584417
5      5                   0.013569500
6      6                   0.021745836
7      7                   0.024301743
8      8                   0.028323187
9      9                   0.029710995
10    10                   0.020706332
11    11                   0.025760934
12    12                   0.025148797
13    13                   0.028520806
14    14                   0.021327549
15    15                   0.024794668
16    16                   0.027986949
17    17                   0.022970945

[[2]]
  layer pland_02_evergreen_broadleaf
1     7                   0.02329869
2    11                   0.02910651
3    12                   0.04234851
4    13                   0.02788104
5    14                   0.01899742
6    15                   0.02639924
7    16                   0.02601143
8    17                   0.03166427
```

My expected output:

```
[[1]]
   layer pland_01_evergreen_needleleaf         pland_02_evergreen_broadleaf    
1      1                   0.016832782                       0            
2      2                   0.024552628                       0              
3      3                   0.024377985                       0                 
4      4                   0.009584417                       0                  
5      5                   0.013569500                       0                     
6      6                   0.021745836                       0                           
7      7                   0.024301743                   0.02329869                            
8      8                   0.028323187                       0                          
9      9                   0.029710995                       0                           
10    10                   0.020706332                       0                             
11    11                   0.025760934                   0.02910651                                 
12    12                   0.025148797                   0.04234851                             
13    13                   0.028520806                   0.02788104                            
14    14                   0.021327549                   0.01899742                               
15    15                   0.024794668                   0.02639924                                  
16    16                   0.027986949                   0.02601143                                  
17    17                   0.022970945                   0.03166427
```

I have tried:

```
do.call(plyr::rbind.fill, test.enc)
```

Though, it does not replace the rows and just fills values in columns with NA's.

Reproducible code:

```
test.enc <- list(structure(list(layer = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17), pland_01_evergreen_needleleaf = c(0.0168327818172984, 
0.0245526278078456, 0.0243779845525292, 0.00958441728108318, 
0.0135694997972973, 0.0217458355, 0.0243017425347303, 0.0283231869863014, 
0.0297109945836134, 0.0207063315181945, 0.0257609335769293, 0.0251487967356828, 
0.0285208063526021, 0.0213275492944468, 0.0247946677520666, 0.0279869491599538, 
0.0229709450323356)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(layer = c(7, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17), 
        pland_02_evergreen_broadleaf = c(0.0232986892474108, 
        0.029106514197793, 0.0423485148880614, 0.0278810399372792, 
        0.0189974225113402, 0.0263992402670516, 0.0260114284210526, 
        0.0316642657775499)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(layer = c(1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
    14, 15, 16, 17), pland_03_deciduous_needleleaf = c(0.0224730632077946, 
    0.0272254714759945, 0.0179234332099727, 0.0233360434693878, 
    0.0289772211061947, 0.0279319832599034, 0.0240684032409326, 
    0.0193554670384615, 0.0279649463078261, 0.0269396070886525, 
    0.0185719102763596, 0.018542528637931, 0.012709947072028, 
    0.04239139)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(layer = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
    12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17), pland_04_deciduous_broadleaf = c(0.0237555990295715, 
    0.0250673634976813, 0.0215182227341075, 0.00714736670909091, 
    0.0290969429050279, 0.0267860332636672, 0.0270534621613419, 
    0.026721714630264, 0.0238709596184027, 0.0249074332489268, 
    0.0304618992970835, 0.0260209517100003, 0.015865886959611, 
    0.0243338004003074, 0.0201179804026253, 0.0332228978795843
    )), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        layer = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
        15, 16, 17), pland_05_mixed_forest = c(0.0205357761652226, 
        0.0241299700965417, 0.0225027270827694, 0.00985684546268657, 
        0.0311072087096774, 0.0252826755994332, 0.0271736973582555, 
        0.0283303792425047, 0.0229465085587453, 0.0262387189000513, 
        0.0349808141373789, 0.0269785067137574, 0.0178032039611502, 
        0.0251414066142756, 0.0237955553523809, 0.0349799640745083
        )), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        layer = c(3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17), pland_06_closed_shrubland = c(0.005861055, 
        0.0247702364814815, 0.0217156349945235, 0.0266147094731707, 
        0.0273557187764706, 0.02247895109375, 0.0314803993053339, 
        0.0199688156521739, 0.0250040668072976, 0.024064520016, 
        0.0289086554672578)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(layer = c(1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 10, 13, 15, 16, 17
    ), pland_07_open_shrubland = c(0.0239835098420742, 0.0196024526993901, 
    0.0275470745648515, 0.0205289891038188, 0.0252871031854839, 
    0.0225145242857143, 0.0277447744846797, 0.0273150363541667, 
    0.0372795540909091, 0.0258269711946903)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -10L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(layer = c(1, 
    2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17), 
        pland_08_woody_savanna = c(0.0234895073226773, 0.0254242177795502, 
        0.0222844341348828, 0.010322404308595, 0.0115202866290984, 
        0.022858064298995, 0.0261324981159272, 0.0269339113300467, 
        0.0272905667936239, 0.0243445938197004, 0.0263085547098274, 
        0.031577225982848, 0.027366790080755, 0.0170917603078201, 
        0.0245166202483043, 0.0230437328068511, 0.0302480713824274
        )), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        layer = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
        14, 15, 16, 17), pland_09_savanna = c(0.024511496338631, 
        0.0263438531740197, 0.0230784856467449, 0.0103841481938194, 
        0.0112631119225057, 0.0218656878147517, 0.0263293450194207, 
        0.0272377655722272, 0.0277590005710358, 0.0248185191981168, 
        0.0264710300465011, 0.0311785029047626, 0.027764701873438, 
        0.018296641767007, 0.0243240673465086, 0.0269793925823536, 
        0.0261431798468939)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(layer = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
    12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17), pland_10_grassland = c(0.0241048000322165, 
    0.0257675668336232, 0.0223383845545, 0.0189068612261722, 
    0.0261390898788855, 0.0261454176785369, 0.0262590636755884, 
    0.0273476886308152, 0.0282016510452861, 0.0249749584240885, 
    0.0269017127896855, 0.0309276372122874, 0.0280081024050942, 
    0.0171571967814629, 0.024706397187938, 0.0229732030207295, 
    0.0271717635000233)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(layer = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
    12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17), pland_11_wetland = c(0.0261045398315745, 
    0.0270077896857178, 0.0228967718773374, 0.0199122837701645, 
    0.0227976864969644, 0.0275306004374101, 0.0271334525693991, 
    0.0285065610334257, 0.0281986960454696, 0.0235630515843985, 
    0.0235566291662858, 0.0272662707441063, 0.0242547847851237, 
    0.020220947639907, 0.0229653844016148, 0.0189523223219292, 
    0.016330738598504)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(layer = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
    12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17), pland_12_cropland = c(0.0247481645364914, 
    0.0269929124824351, 0.0233212451104437, 0.0209935752243073, 
    0.027662987546265, 0.0267526016850953, 0.0264659030703554, 
    0.0276911097027454, 0.027704723980107, 0.0258298011360007, 
    0.0293761963259958, 0.0304401704151498, 0.0297272977127787, 
    0.0191320152910558, 0.022300483848187, 0.0310418860633282, 
    0.0194552407910497)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(layer = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
    12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17), pland_13_urban = c(0.0250541999489398, 
    0.0249789151674128, 0.0219325183761915, 0.0174050192638298, 
    0.0198481538465096, 0.0273040101927991, 0.0261348274108392, 
    0.0274315478205557, 0.0284040130969821, 0.0255357946798584, 
    0.0276680704963855, 0.0283009734389356, 0.0273947664869961, 
    0.0191846595896345, 0.0225736950645381, 0.0185572109335283, 
    0.0266912368721673)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(layer = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
    12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17), pland_14_mosiac = c(0.0244553100335083, 
    0.0265608905797148, 0.0230754220937747, 0.0126737591788462, 
    0.0208868797777778, 0.0264543431506849, 0.0271490616452074, 
    0.0275509256793189, 0.0274870231454383, 0.0260302106124036, 
    0.0294514198552019, 0.0317358807321971, 0.0303629153539886, 
    0.0191054718841496, 0.0221332367959672, 0.0332987653767865, 
    0.0153846531471452)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(layer = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
    12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17), pland_15_barren = c(0.0254695416164035, 
    0.0260217783555025, 0.0278294141356033, 0.022098210265976, 
    0.0232223153248193, 0.0277460892260692, 0.0280945051729643, 
    0.0308188510180505, 0.0283990843854084, 0.0282966180792079, 
    0.0292701060708535, 0.02484902225, 0.0202313840629426, 0.02730348265625, 
    0.0252544010927835, 0.012387523087037, 0.0243783162068618
    )), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Maybe you want something like: `Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y, all=TRUE), test.enc)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `merge`and as you have many columns to be added you can call it using `Reduce`.

```
Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y, all=TRUE), test.enc)
#   layer pland_01_evergreen_needleleaf pland_02_evergreen_broadleaf pland_03_deciduous_needleleaf pland_04_deciduous_broadleaf pland_05_mixed_forest pland_06_closed_shrubland pland_07_open_shrubland pland_08_woody_savanna pland_09_savanna pland_10_grassland pland_11_wetland pland_12_cropland pland_13_urban pland_14_mosiac pland_15_barren
#1      1                   0.016832782                           NA                    0.02247306                  0.023755599           0.020535776                        NA              0.02398351             0.02348951       0.02451150         0.02410480       0.02610454        0.02474816     0.02505420      0.02445531      0.02546954
#2      2                   0.024552628                           NA                    0.02722547                  0.025067363           0.024129970                        NA              0.01960245             0.02542422       0.02634385         0.02576757       0.02700779        0.02699291     0.02497892      0.02656089      0.02602178
#3      3                   0.024377985                           NA                    0.01792343                  0.021518223           0.022502727               0.005861055                      NA             0.02228443       0.02307849         0.02233838       0.02289677        0.02332125     0.02193252      0.02307542      0.02782941
#4      4                   0.009584417                           NA                            NA                  0.007147367           0.009856845                        NA                      NA             0.01032240       0.01038415         0.01890686       0.01991228        0.02099358     0.01740502      0.01267376      0.02209821
#5      5                   0.013569500                           NA                            NA                           NA                    NA               0.024770236              0.02754707             0.01152029       0.01126311         0.02613909       0.02279769        0.02766299     0.01984815      0.02088688      0.02322232
#6      6                   0.021745836                           NA                            NA                  0.029096943           0.031107209               0.021715635              0.02052899             0.02285806       0.02186569         0.02614542       0.02753060        0.02675260     0.02730401      0.02645434      0.02774609
#7      7                   0.024301743                   0.02329869                    0.02333604                  0.026786033           0.025282676               0.026614709              0.02528710             0.02613250       0.02632935         0.02625906       0.02713345        0.02646590     0.02613483      0.02714906      0.02809451
#8      8                   0.028323187                           NA                    0.02897722                  0.027053462           0.027173697                        NA                      NA             0.02693391       0.02723777         0.02734769       0.02850656        0.02769111     0.02743155      0.02755093      0.03081885
#9      9                   0.029710995                           NA                    0.02793198                  0.026721715           0.028330379                        NA                      NA             0.02729057       0.02775900         0.02820165       0.02819870        0.02770472     0.02840401      0.02748702      0.02839908
#10    10                   0.020706332                           NA                    0.02406840                  0.023870960           0.022946509               0.027355719              0.02251452             0.02434459       0.02481852         0.02497496       0.02356305        0.02582980     0.02553579      0.02603021      0.02829662
#11    11                   0.025760934                   0.02910651                    0.01935547                  0.024907433           0.026238719               0.022478951                      NA             0.02630855       0.02647103         0.02690171       0.02355663        0.02937620     0.02766807      0.02945142      0.02927011
#12    12                   0.025148797                   0.04234851                    0.02796495                  0.030461899           0.034980814                        NA                      NA             0.03157723       0.03117850         0.03092764       0.02726627        0.03044017     0.02830097      0.03173588      0.02484902
#13    13                   0.028520806                   0.02788104                    0.02693961                  0.026020952           0.026978507               0.031480399              0.02774477             0.02736679       0.02776470         0.02800810       0.02425478        0.02972730     0.02739477      0.03036292      0.02023138
#14    14                   0.021327549                   0.01899742                    0.01857191                  0.015865887           0.017803204               0.019968816                      NA             0.01709176       0.01829664         0.01715720       0.02022095        0.01913202     0.01918466      0.01910547      0.02730348
#15    15                   0.024794668                   0.02639924                    0.01854253                  0.024333800           0.025141407               0.025004067              0.02731504             0.02451662       0.02432407         0.02470640       0.02296538        0.02230048     0.02257370      0.02213324      0.02525440
#16    16                   0.027986949                   0.02601143                    0.01270995                  0.020117980           0.023795555               0.024064520              0.03727955             0.02304373       0.02697939         0.02297320       0.01895232        0.03104189     0.01855721      0.03329877      0.01238752
#17    17                   0.022970945                   0.03166427                    0.04239139                  0.033222898           0.034979964               0.028908655              0.02582697             0.03024807       0.02614318         0.02717176       0.01633074        0.01945524     0.02669124      0.01538465      0.02437832
```